# I can't Upload photo by Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to upload an image with Selenium(Python3) but
I can't...
The error is

```
element not interactable.
```

However, the photo path is correct...
What could be the cause?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://website.com/signup')
time.sleep(1)

# Upload profile photo
upload_photo = driver.find_element_by_id("profilePic")
upload_photo.click()
upload_photo.send_keys("/Users/mypc/Desktop/a.jpg")
time.sleep(1)
```

Also, I tried the following code but same error.

```
# Upload profile photo
driver.find_element_by_id("profilePic").send_keys("/Users/mypc/Desktop/a.jpg")
time.sleep(1)
```

This is the element.

```
<div _ngcontent-rgg-c3="" class="profilePicPreview cursor-pointer" id="profilePic"><!----></div>
```

Comment: `element not interactable` is not referring to the path of your photo but the html element itself. Which line of code is giving you that error? click() or send_keys(...)?

Comment: I just reazlied that your "also,..." answers my question. Has the profilePic element fully loaded into the DOM? If you are executing the send_keys method prior to the profilePic element loading, then it will not be interactable. Have you tried increasing the first time.sleep amount?

Comment: upload photo.click() works because I can see the upload window came up. sendkeys(...) seems not to work.

Comment: have you tried using pyautogui?

Comment: Ohh I misunderstand element!! Sorry I missed choose element. correct one is upload_photo = driver.find_element_by_id("fileuploaderPic") Thanks!